# ¿Uso de EditText Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy incursionando en Android Studio, ¿Cómo podría enviar un texto de un EditText a un TextView sin el uso de un boton? Especificamente, ¿Cómo podría hacer una multiplicación y poder mostrarlo en un TextView con la tecla "Enter" del celular?.

La solución más cercana que he encontrado es esta, pero se me cierra la APP, ocurre un error.

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnKeyListener {

EditText txtCien, txtCincuenta, txtVeinte, txtDiez, txtCinco, txtDos, txtMil;
TextView tvCien, tvCincuenta, tvVeinte, tvDiez, tvCinco, tvDos, tvMil;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtCien = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCien);
    //tvCien.setText(Integer.parseInt(txtCien.getText().toString())*100000);
    txtCien.setOnKeyListener(this);


}

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&&(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pucha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Con respecto a el error que obtienes siempre acostumbra agregar el error que se muestra en el LogCat, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando un `EditText` y requieres detectar cuando se da clic en la tecla "Done" del menù contextual, debes usar el listener [OnEditorActionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener) , cuando detecte la tecla "Done" puedes mostrar el resultado en tu `TextView`.

```
    //Obtiene referencia de TextView
    final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);  

    txtCien = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCien);
    txtCien.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                 //Realiza operaciòn y la escribe en TextView.
                 textView.setText(String.valueOf(2 * 5));

                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
```